# enviar o valor de uma variavel de um programa para outro - python

Tags: python, variáveis

Boa tarde. eu estou fazendo um programa em python que vai usar as teclas numéricas para abrir aplicativos e(ou) sites.

Eu criei 2 códigos: 1 para configurar (setar os links que o usuário vai querer acessar), e o outro para executar.

O código do setup é esse:

```
def setup_init():
    hotkeys_num = int(input(('Quantos atalhos vc vai querer (0-9)? ')))

    lista = []
    i = 1
    while i <= hotkeys_num:
    a = input('digite o link/diretório: ')
    lista.append(a)
    i += 1
    print('='*51)
    print('Configuração concluida. Stream deck de pobre ativo.')
    print('='*51)

setup_init()
```

main:

```
print(a)
```

Por enquanto, eu só quero que o setup envie o a lista de links/diretórios para o outro programa.
Alguém sabe como eu faço isso ?

Comment: Ou por arquivo de configuração, OS pipes, no Windows pelo registro ou na Intranet por broadcasting ou Web via API.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode importar a função fazendo:
arquivo main

```py
from nomeDoOutroArquivoSemExtensão import setup_init

# Caso queira importar somente a variavel a, basta fazer
from nomeDoOutroArquivoSemExtensão import a
```

Porém, você está tentando imprimir uma variável local (a). Para que consiga imprimi-la no arquivo main, você deve declará-la como global dentro da função. Contudo, vale ressaltar que isso pode gerar um problema caso a função não seja chamada, já que a variável não será declarada e será utilizada no arquivo main mesmo assim. Portanto, pode se declarar 'a' fora da função para evitar isso. Por exemplo:

```py
a = 0
def setup_init():
    hotkeys_num = int(input(('Quantos atalhos vc vai querer (0-9)? ')))

    lista = []
    i = 1
    while i <= hotkeys_num:
    global a
    a = input('digite o link/diretório: ')
    lista.append(a)
    i += 1
    print('='*51)
    print('Configuração concluida. Stream deck de pobre ativo.')
    print('='*51)
```

Comment: Obrigado, vou estar amanhã.